# Excel: Auto-populate outputs based on input change in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a very complex financial model made up whose output changes based on the 2 inputs. I want to make a table where the column has all possible values of input 1 and row has all possible value of input 2. Each cell in the table should have the output corresponding to the two inputs. How do I go about this?

Can you provide a link or a function that I can use to do this?

Comment: If you can write a formula using Excel's notation for your financial model, this is straightforward. Enter the values for input 1 in column A, starting with A2.  Enter the values for input 2 in row 1, starting with B1.  In cell B2, enter the formula for your model, but replace every instance of input 1 with "$A2" (don't type the quotes) and every instance of input 2 with "B$1" (again, no quotes). Fill the formula down to the last value in column A, and then fill the entire selection (B2:Bn) to the right until you reach the last value in row 1.

Comment: Thanks. However, the model is too complex to be put in one formula. Hence, I need a function which populate the values based on the two inputs.

Comment: You'll have to provide much more detail about your problem.  How is the result calculated, are there simultaneous equations that need to be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Write a VBA script/macro to iterate through the cells in your table, pasting the grid coordinates into your input value cells, recalculate, then copy the output the grid location.  Given your 2-dimensional grid you should only require to FOR loops.

Something like this

```vb
FOR i to <Input_1_Max> 
  FOR j to <Input_2_Max> 
     Range(Input_1) = i
     Range(Input_2) = j
     Application.Calculate
     Cells(i,j).value = Range(Output).value
   Next j
Next i
```